# Why is `tac file | grep foo' (piping) faster than `grep foo < <(tac file)' (process substitution)?

Tags: bash, grep, performance, efficiency

*This question was motivated by "[Reverse grepping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146100/reverse-grepping)", about grepping a huge file from bottom up.*

[@chaos said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146106/45600):

> ```
> tac file | grep whatever
> ```
>
> Or a bit more effective:
>
> ```
> grep whatever < <(tac file)
> ```

[@vinc17 said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146100/reverse-grepping#comment236069_146106):

> The `< <(tac filename)` should be as fast as a pipe

There are also many interesting comments from other users.

My questions:

- What is the difference between `|` and `< <()`?
- Why is one faster than other?
- And which is really faster?
- Why did no one suggest `xargs`?

Comment: Note that it's `< <(...)` short for `0< <(...)`, not `<<(...)`.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for **fixing "greping"** to "grepping" - I came just back form **english.SE** to fix it; I got **really curious** how it's right, and **why**. Learned a lot about English in a short time. **See 6 answers** at [Deriving a word for the activity of using a tool from the tool name (“grep”)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186811/deriving-a-word-for-the-activity-of-using-a-tool-from-the-tool-name-grep)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I just looked at the title of the linked question, for consistent spelling ;-)

Comment: I knew it was inconsistent - but I did not know who's right ;) I strongly preferred "greping", because the additional "p" in "grepping" somehow becomes part of the command name - which felt "very wrong" to me - just made no sense at all... But it turned out that the guys over at english.SE made me accept "grepping" as right in about an hour and 6 answers :)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Edited the example to match.

Comment: No one suggested `xargs` because `xargs` is not applicable to this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The construction `<(tac file)` causes to shell to:

- Create a pipe with a name

  - On systems such as Linux and SysV which have `/dev/fd`, a regular pipe is used, and `/dev/fd/<the-file-descriptor-of-the-pipe>` is used as the name.
  - On other systems, a named pipe is used, which requires creating an actual file entry on disk.
- Launch the command `tac file` and connect it to one end of the pipe.
- Replace the whole construction on the command line with the name of the pipe.

After the replacement, the command line becomes:

```
grep whatever < /tmp/whatever-name-the-shell-used-for-the-named-pipe
```

And then `grep` is executed, and it reads its standard input (which is the pipe), reads it, and searches for its first argument in that.

So the end result is the same as with...

```
tac file | grep whatever
```

...in that the same two programs are launched and a pipe is still used to connect them. But the `<( ... )` construction is more convoluted because it involves more steps and may involve a temporary file (the named pipe).

The `<( ... )` construct is an extension, and is not available in the standard POSIX bourne shell nor on platforms that do not support `/dev/fd` or named pipes. For this reason alone, because the two alternatives being considered are exactly equivalent in functionality, the more portable `command | other-command` form is a better choice.

The `<( ... )` construction should be slower because of the additional convolution, but it's only in the startup phase and I don't expect the difference to be easily measurable.

*NOTE*: On Linux SysV platforms, `< ( ... )` does not use named pipes but instead uses regular pipes. Regular pipes (indeed all file descriptors) can be referred to by the special named `/dev/fd/<file-descriptor-number` so that's what the shell uses as a name for the pipe. In this way it avoids creating a real named pipe with a bona fide temporary filename in the real filesystem. Although the `/dev/fd` trick is what was used to implement this feature when it originally appears in `ksh`, it is an optimization: on platforms that don't support this, a regular named pipe in the real filesystem is used as described above.

*ALSO NOTE*: To describe the syntax as `<<( ... )` is misleading. In fact it's `<( ... )`, which is replaced with the name of a pipe, and then the other `<` character which prefixes the whole thing is separate from this syntax and it's the regular well-known syntax for redirecting input from a file.

Comment: process substitution appeared on ksh and was using /dev/fd/n (a SysV feature) from the start (and was not available on systems that didn't support it). `bash` and `zsh` added support for named pipes for systems that lacked /dev/fd/n later.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah, that is interesting history, thanks. So it's originally a `ksh` feature, not a standard POSIX feature! Sure enough, `dash` doesn't appear to support it. That's one more reason to avoid it when there's an equivalent alternative available using basic POSIX features.

Comment: It's not only SysV (SysV generally referring to a reference implementation and also to a family of OSes) and Linux. Solaris, all modern BSDs and probably many others support /dev/fd/n. (actually, the Linux one is significantly different from that of others as it's implemented as symlinks to original resources while in other Unices /dev/fd/n are special devices which when open, work like dup (which is why I said on Linux, and Linux only, /dev/fd/n on a pipe acts as a named pipe)).

Comment: I think process substitution `< <(command)` is preferable in regard to the pipe `|`. As explained by gnouc, `|` requires each command to run in a subshell while process substitution leaves the pipe open and feeds the command from the stdout. There is more here:  http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst  and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

Comment: @val0x00ff The `command | command` pipe construction is about as efficient as you can get. The shell uses `fork()` to create each new processes in a pipeline; but then `fork()` is *universally* used to create new processes — that's not considered a subshell.

Answer (score 7):

> What is difference between | and <<()?

There is a difference between them:

- `|` cause each command run in a separated subshell.
- `<()` run the command, which is substituted in background.

For the next two question, we will do some `strace`:

`pipe`:

```
$ strace -fc bash -c 'tac /usr/share/dict/american-english | grep qwerty'
$ time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.008120        2707         3         1 wait4
  0.00    0.000000           0       352           read
  0.00    0.000000           0       229           write
  0.00    0.000000           0        20         2 open
  0.00    0.000000           0        29         2 close
  0.00    0.000000           0        40        17 stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        19           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0       117           lseek
  0.00    0.000000           0        38           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        18           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        25           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0        22           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0        18           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigreturn
  0.00    0.000000           0         3         2 ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0        24        12 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           pipe
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           dup2
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getpid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 getpeername
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           clone
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           uname
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           getuid
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           getgid
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           geteuid
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           getegid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getppid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getpgrp
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           time
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.008120                  1034        37 total
```

`Process Substitution`:

```
$ strace -fc bash -c 'grep qwerty < <(tac /usr/share/dict/american-english)'
$ time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 99.14    0.016001        4000         4         2 wait4
  0.46    0.000075           0       229           write
  0.24    0.000038           0       341           read
  0.16    0.000026           1        24           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0        21         2 open
  0.00    0.000000           0        27           close
  0.00    0.000000           0        40        17 stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        19           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0       117           lseek
  0.00    0.000000           0        38           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        18           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        35           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0        24           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigreturn
  0.00    0.000000           0         3         2 ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0        24        12 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           pipe
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           dup2
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getpid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 getpeername
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           clone
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           uname
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           getuid
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           getgid
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           geteuid
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           getegid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getppid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getpgrp
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           time
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.016140                  1046        37 total
```

> Why something faster than other?
>
> And what is really faster?

You can see, `process substitution` is slower than `pipe` in this case, because it use more system call. Both spend much time to wait for child processes, but `process substitution` use more `wait4()` syscall, and use more time for each call than `pipe`.

> Why no one suggest xargs ?

I don't think `xargs` can help anything here, this is not its jobs.

**Update**

As @Gilles's suggested, I do a test with bigger file, 2GB random data generated from `/dev/urandom`. It shows that `pipe` is really faster than `process substitution`.

`pipe`:

```
$ strace -fc bash -c 'tac sample.txt | grep qwerty'
$ time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 81.15    8.284959     2761653         3         1 wait4
 17.89    1.825959           2    780959           read
  0.91    0.092708           0    524286           write
  0.05    0.005364           0    262146           lseek
  0.00    0.000000           0        20         2 open
  0.00    0.000000           0        29         2 close
  0.00    0.000000           0        40        17 stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        19           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        38           mmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        18           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        25           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0        22           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0        18           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigreturn
  0.00    0.000000           0         3         2 ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0        24        12 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           pipe
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           dup2
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getpid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 getpeername
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           clone
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           uname
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           getuid
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           getgid
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           geteuid
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           getegid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getppid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getpgrp
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           time
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00   10.208990               1567727        37 total
```

`process substitution`:

```
$ strace -fc bash -c 'grep qwerty < <(tac sample.txt)'
$ time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 99.51   13.912869     3478217         4         2 wait4
  0.38    0.053373           0    655269           read
  0.09    0.013084           0    524286           write
  0.02    0.002454           0    262146           lseek
  0.00    0.000030           1        38           mmap
  0.00    0.000024           1        24        12 access
  0.00    0.000000           0        21         2 open
  0.00    0.000000           0        27           close
  0.00    0.000000           0        40        17 stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        19           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0        18           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0         6           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0        24           brk
  0.00    0.000000           0        35           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0        24           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           rt_sigreturn
  0.00    0.000000           0         3         2 ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           pipe
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           dup2
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getpid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 getpeername
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           clone
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           uname
  0.00    0.000000           0         1         1 fcntl
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           getrlimit
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           getuid
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           getgid
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           geteuid
  0.00    0.000000           0        13           getegid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getppid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getpgrp
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           time
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00   13.981834               1442060        37 total
```

Comment: process substitution leverages `/dev/fd/n`, it doesn't use named pipes (though on Linux, and linux only /dev/fd/n behave like named pipes when n is a file descriptor to a pipe (named or not)). On systems that don't support /dev/fd/n, some shells fall back to using named pipes.

Comment: Added a note. But it seems that process subsitution is only support when system supports named pipe: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html. And from this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution, it said process substitution use named pipe?

Comment: Well, wikipedia is wrong here (and bash-centric). Simply run `ls -l <(:)` to verify that it doesn't use named pipes.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: So can you clarify `What is named pipe?`. I read here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe

Comment: @Gnouc a named pipe is a pipe that is connected to a name in the filesystem. It is created using `mkfifo` as described in the Wikipedia article. A named pipe is one of those "special" types of files you can sometimes see in the filesystem, like UNIX domain sockets, character devices, and block devices.

Comment: @Celada: Thanks, I got it! Fixed my answer.

Comment: When running the strace command several times, I notice that the output changes a bit, and that both solutions are rather equivalent. This becomes even more visible on a big file (several MB's).

Comment: @vinc17: because after you run several time, the file contetnt can be cached in memory.

Comment: @Gnouc Even when the contents are cached, timings vary. If data is not cached, I'd say that both methods would be even more equivalent since what will be measured is the disk speed (and again, timings may vary).

Comment: +1 for showing usage of `strace`

Comment: The timing result here doesn't show anything about the relative speed of the two methods. Below 0.1s, timings are pretty much random (measurement uncertainty due to whatever else is executing in the background).

Comment: @Gilles: So do you have any ideal to make the test more *truly*? Can be a bigger file make different?

Comment: You can use a bigger file, which will benchmark the case of large files. You can use a small file on a loop with enough iterations to last a decent time (~1s is fine), which will benchmark the case of small files.

Comment: @Gilles: Add a test with 2GB random data file, `pipe` ~4s faster than `process substitution`.

Answer (score 1):

I was **not** able to replicate the results shown by [cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146276/257010). Even with a 2GB file, in Bash 5 on MacOS Mojave, I see very similar timings between process substitution and pipe. This makes sense to me as the overhead involved in a call is going to be *minimal* compared to the actual processing of that call for a 2GB file, so running one iteration of using process substitution vs a pipe will be down to randomness / which command was run first to cache the file content.

I *was* able to replicate the findings [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127645/performance-differences-between-pipelines-and-process-substitution) which show that **process substitution is faster than pipes** over several thousand instances of making these calls.

Here are the commands I ran, and the output:

**pipe.sh**:

```bsh
shopt -s lastpipe
for i in {1..5000}; do
    echo foo bar |
    while read; do
        echo $REPLY >/dev/null
    done
done
```

**proc-sub.sh**:

```bsh
for i in {1..5000}; do
    while read; do
        echo $REPLY >/dev/null
    done < <(echo foo bar)
done
```

**pipe-no-lastpipe.sh**:

```bsh
for i in {1..5000}; do
    echo foo bar |
    while read; do
        echo $REPLY >/dev/null
    done
done
```

**Test**:

```bsh
time ./proc-sub.sh

real    0m9.505s
user    0m1.875s
sys     0m10.705s

time ./pipe.sh

real    0m14.036s
user    0m4.583s
sys     0m14.193s

time ./pipe-no-lastpipe.sh

real    0m16.696s
user    0m3.055s
sys     0m18.057s
```