# Why process substitution is faster than pipe in this case?

Tags: bash, pipe, process-substitution

I am wondering why

```
ls -1 | 
while read file; do 
     echo $file; tail -n 100 $file > >(sleep 1 && cat > $file)
done
```

is faster than

```
ls -1 | 
while read file; do 
    echo $file; tail -n 100 $file | (sleep 1 && cat > $file)
done
```

?

If there are 100 files in a directory then:

- the second command takes almost 100 seconds to process
- the first command is processed almost immediately.

Comment: That's because `bash` doesn't wait for the termination of that process substitution (which could be seen as [a bug](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2017-12/msg00002.html)). See [The process substitution output is out of the order](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/403788) for details.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas; This says different : https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146263/186463

Comment: @haccks, in that case `grep < <(cmd)`, while the shell doesn't wait for `cmd`, `grep` does as it waits for eof on its stdin. Again, see details at the link I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas; you said "*bash doesn't wait for the termination of that process substitution*". Isn't that true for pipes too?

Comment: @haccks, no. `bash` waits for all pipe components. All shells wait for the last (right-most) pipe components, some don't wait for the other ones.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas; Pipe components run in the background (in subshell) as well as process substitution. Then why is this difference? Also in `cmd1 | cmd2`, does bash will wait for `cmd1` too?

Comment: All pipe components run in subshells in bash, but  not in background unless the whole pipeline is put in background with `&` (note that _background_/_foreground_ only apply to interactive shells, that's terminology linked to job control in terminals). process substitution are put in background unless they're  run from a subshell itself run in foreground. In any case, that's not what I'm talking about. I'm talking about the shell waiting for the termination of processes it starts before continuing with the next command (tbc)

Comment: (continued). In `cmd1 | cmd2; cmd3`, bash waits for the termination of cmd1 and cmd2 (the processes it  started to execute them) before running `cmd3`. In `cmd1 > >(cmd2); cmd3`, `bash` only waits for `cmd1` before running `cmd3`. `cmd2` may very well continue running while `cmd3` is running. Try `echo foo | (sleep 1; cat); ps` vs `echo foo > >(sleep 1; cat); ps`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas can you please give me a reference where it says that process substitution run in background or the command in the process substitution is not waited for?

Comment: @haccks, it's easy to verify (like with the examples I gave above). For foreground vs background, use `ps -j`. See also the links I gave including the discussion on the bash mailing list.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I already tested. Just curious to know where the docs says it. Language laywer problem :)

Comment: See `info bash "Process Substitution"`. They key word is _asynchronously_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas that's the confusion point. Pipes components also run asynchronously.

Comment: @haccks From the [Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#Pipelines) documentation: If the pipeline is not executed asynchronously (see Lists), the shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to complete.

Comment: So in both cases the components run asynchronously, but in the case of pipelines it still waits for them all to finish (unless you run the whole pipeline in the background with `&`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a pipeline, the shell runs each command in the pipeline concurrently, and waits for all of them to finish before going to the next command. This is explained in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#Pipelines):

> If the pipeline is not executed asynchronously (see [Lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists)), the shell waits for all commands in the pipeline to complete.

When the above refers to executing the pipeline asynchronously, it's talking about running the whole pipeline in the background with `&`.

When you use process substitution the shell doesn't wait for it to complete. The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) simply says:

> The process *list* is run asynchronously, and its input or output appears as a filename.

Comment: I think I was confused with the term "asynchronous" and "concurrent". In  case of pipe, elements run concurrently. But here I think "asynchronous" is specifically mean running process in the background, correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: That seems to be how the manual is using the term.