# For with read value

Tags: shell-script, command-line, scripting, variable, read

In what way does the final value of number being assigned by `read var number` (and we enter 5) and `number=5` differ? I was making this **for** loop:

```
read var number
#number=5
factorial=1
i=1
for i in `seq 1 $number`
do
        let factorial=factorial*i
done
echo $factorial
```

when I noticed that if the number has the value assigned by the read, rather than direct assigning, it doesn't enter my for. I'm guessing it's because of the data type.

Comment: **Please don't do this in Bash.**  It's just not the right tool for this job.  It's really not a *programming language* in the sense of dealing with computation, data structures or algorithms; see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303387/135943 (and the links from there) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the first line to

```
read number
```

you’ll get the behaviour you’re looking for.

```
read var number
```

reads two values and stores them in variables named `var` and `number`. If you only input one value, `seq 1 $number` expands to `seq 1` which is just `1`.

Comment: Ah, I was mislead by something ambiguous, saying that the syntax for reading is read var [var_1 var_2 var_3 ... var_n]. I thought var was telling the interpreter that they are variables.

Comment: @Peter If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.