# Why do I have "command not found" in my script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution

I am writing a Nagios plugin and I have a "command not found" when I run it. What is wrong? Why 127.0.0.1 (or localhost as well) is not recognized? When I run just the snmp request - I have a simple number as an output - so everything works perfectly.

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

answer=snmpget 127.0.0.1 -v 2c -c public .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.9.0 | grep -Eo 
'[0-9]+$'

case $answer in
    [1-2]*)
        echo "OK"
        exit 0
        ;;
    [3-50]*)
        echo "WARNING"
        exit 1
        ;;
    [51-100]*)
        echo "CRITICAL"
        exit 2
        ;;
    *)
        echo "UNKNOWN"
        exit 3
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable assignment is not correct.  You are looking for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution):

```
answer=$(snmpget 127.0.0.1 -v 2c -c public .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.9.0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$')
```

As you have written it you are setting `answer=snmpget` as an environmental variable for the command: `127.0.0.1` with options: `-v 2c -c public .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.11.9.0`

Also note `[3-50]` and `[51-100]` almost certainly will not do what you intend.  See: [Can I use comparison operators in case?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/384613/237982)