# Bash script inheritance? Calling a function from another script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this line:

`trap 'jobs -p | xargs kill -9' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT`

it is repeated in many bash shell scripts I have.

What is the best way to share this code? Can I call a bash function perhaps?

In reality, I am creating a framework and the user will be expected to write some glue shell scripts. What would be nice if the user's shell scripts could inherit from a base shell script, somehow. Or they could just call bash functions that pre-exist somehow.

The **problem** is that if I create a bash function like so:

```
// a.sh
function trap_and_kill_child_jobs {
    trap 'jobs -p | xargs kill -9' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT
}
```

and call it from another script like so:

```
// b.sh
source ./a.sh
trap_and_kill_child_jobs
sh -c 'sleep 10000 &' &   # I want this process to be killed by `trap_and_kill_child_jobs`
./run-some-tests.js
```

the caller script (`b.sh`) does **not** actually experience the trap. The 'child jobs' created by b.sh will continue running.

Comment: *"What would be nice if the user's shell scripts could inherit from a base shell script, somehow."*  **Please** don't use shell for this.  It's [*not really a language.*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303387/135943)  It IS for glue scripts, and nothing else.  Every shell scripting "framework" I've seen (without exception) is (a) complex, (b) buggy, (c) a nightmare for the poor sap who gets to inherit and attempt to maintain it.

Comment: Yeah I hear ya, this is just for putting one shell script in between stuff, I doubt very many poor saps will be sapped.

Comment: @Wildcard can you speak to why calling the `trap_and_kill_child_jobs` function wouldn't invoke trap to actually work?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your script, no, I can't.  You don't *show* any child jobs being created.

Comment: Yeah I see, I updated the OP to show a job being created, hopefully it makes sense now

Comment: Thanks.  You need to get into the details of how `node` works.  I'm not a JS developer, but I expect what's going on is that `node` is forking and starting some other processes, *and then exiting.*  So it won't show up in your "jobs" list at all.  **Again, a shell scripting *framework* is almost invariably code smell.**  You have architectural problems here; you're trying to use the shell to keep track of internal workings of JS when it really can't do that.

Comment: mmm `node server.js` is just starting a server that will listen on a port, the process will be kept alive indefinitely until it receives a signal. To elaborate, calling `trap_and_kill_child_jobs` works if the function is declared the same script, but not if the function is sourced from another script. By "works" I mean the nodejs server is killed by trap when the process that executed the bash script exits.

Comment: In that case I suggest you make some **reproducible** versions that illustrate what you're talking about.  Perhaps the `trap` command really does work differently in functions.  Try using the `sleep` command and perhaps `sh -c 'sleep 10000 &'` and so forth to get some jobs to start other processes.  See if you can make the sleep commands get killed/not get killed.  Again, see [the fundamental philosophy of debugging](http://www.codesimplicity.com/post/the-fundamental-philosophy-of-debugging/)—make it possible for someone else to *look* at the same phenomena you see.

Comment: So like Docker? :) Otherwise reproducible is very hard to do unless you have node.js on your system etc. But yeah I thought someone might know what I was talking about without the deets. I will change out the `node server.js` command for the sleep command you mentioned.

Comment: *Minimal* reproducible example.  If it is really true that `trap` doesn't operate correctly/the same when run in a function sourced from another file (which I doubt is actually the case), it will be possible to reproduce this behavior *without node.js at all,* using only standard shell commands.

Comment: I agree, so that's why I changed it to `sh` instead of `node` in the example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65202/discussion-between-wildcard-and-alexander-mills).

Comment: run the trap, drop the bass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be enough create a script file that contain your framework functions like this:

**/tmp/framework.sh**

```
# Define a serie of functions of your framework...
function framework_function_1() {
    echo "function 1 executed"
}

function framework_function_2() {
    echo "function 2 executed"  
}

# And put here anything you want to be executed right away (like the trap)
echo "framework.sh was executed"
```

Then include it in the rest of your scripts like this:

**/tmp/b.sh**

```
# Include the framework:
.  /tmp/framework.sh

echo "Script b.sh was executed"
# Calling a framework's function
framework_function_2
```

With this the execution of b.sh (and any other script including framework.sh) will be like:

```
$ /tmp/b.sh 
framework.sh was executed
Script b.sh was executed
function 2 executed
```

Note that `. /tmp/framework.sh` is the same as `source /tmp/framework.sh`.

Comment: yeah for some reason when I call `trap_and_kill_child_jobs` from `b.sh` it doesn't actually work..maybe you can try my example and see if it works?

Comment: It will work if you change your trap to:
  `trap 'kill -9 $(jobs -p)' SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT`