# How do I shift a bash array at some index in the middle?

Tags: bash, variable, array

```
1  #!/bin/bash
2  # query2.sh
3
4  numbers=(53 8 12 9 784 69 8 7 1)
5  i=4
6
7  echo ${numbers[@]} # <--- this echoes "53 8 12 9 784 69 8 7 1" to stdout.
8  echo ${numbers[i]} # <--- this echoes "784" to stdout.
9
10 unset numbers[i]
11
12 echo ${numbers[@]} # <--- this echoes "53 8 12 9 69 8 7 1" to stdout.
13 echo ${numbers[i]} # <--- stdout is blank.
```

Why, in line 13, is the stdout blank, considering that the array seems to have been updated judging by line 12's stdout?

And therefore, what should I do to get the intended answer, "69"?

Comment: Considering the type of coding work this question implies, you should take warning: see [Is there something wrong with my script or is Bash much slower than Python?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303387/135943)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`unset` removes an element.  It doesn't renumber the remaining elements.

We can use `declare -p` to see exactly what happens to `numbers`:

```
$ unset "numbers[i]"
$ declare -p numbers
declare -a numbers=([0]="53" [1]="8" [2]="12" [3]="9" [5]="69" [6]="8" [7]="7" [8]="1")
```

Observe the `numbers` no longer has an element `4`.

#### Another example

Observe:

```
$ a=()
$ a[1]="element 1"
$ a[22]="element 22"
$ declare -p a
declare -a a=([1]="element 1" [22]="element 22")
```

Array `a` has no elements 2 through 21.  Bash does not require that array indices be consecutive.

#### Suggested method to force a renumbering of the indices

Let's start with the `numbers` array with the missing element `4`:

```
$ declare -p numbers
declare -a numbers=([0]="53" [1]="8" [2]="12" [3]="9" [5]="69" [6]="8" [7]="7" [8]="1")
```

If we would like the indices to change, then:

```
$ numbers=("${numbers[@]}")
$ declare -p numbers
declare -a numbers=([0]="53" [1]="8" [2]="12" [3]="9" [4]="69" [5]="8" [6]="7" [7]="1")
```

There is now an element number `4` and it has value `69`.

#### Alternate method to remove an element & renumber array in one step

Again, let's define `numbers`:

```
$ numbers=(53 8 12 9 784 69 8 7 1)
```

As suggested by [Toby Speight](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/112566/toby-speight) in the comments, a method to remove the fifth element (at index 4) and renumber the remaining elements all in one step:

```
$ numbers=("${numbers[@]:0:4}" "${numbers[@]:5}")
$ declare -p numbers
declare -a numbers=([0]="53" [1]="8" [2]="12" [3]="9" [4]="69" [5]="8" [6]="7" [7]="1")
```

As you can see, the fifth element was removed and all remaining elements were renumbered.

`${numbers[@]:0:4}` slices array `numbers`: it takes the first four elements starting with element 0.

Similarly, `${numbers[@]:5}` slice array `numbers`: it takes all elements starting with element 5 and continuing to the end of the array.

#### Obtaining the indices of an array

The *values* of an array can be obtained with `${a[@]}`.  To find the *indices* (or *keys*) that correspond to those values, use `${!a[@]}`.

For example, consider again our array `numbers` with the missing element `4`:

```
$ declare -p numbers
declare -a numbers=([0]="53" [1]="8" [2]="12" [3]="9" [5]="69" [6]="8" [7]="7" [8]="1")
```

To see which indices are assigned:

```
$ echo "${!numbers[@]}"
0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8
```

Again, `4` is missing from the list of indices.

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> The `unset` builtin is used to destroy arrays.  **`unset name[subscript]`** destroys the array element at index `subscript`.
> Negative  subscripts  to  indexed arrays are interpreted as described above.  Care must be taken to avoid unwanted side effects caused by pathname expansion.  **`unset name`**, where `name` is an array, or `unset name[subscript]`, where `subscript` is  **`*`**  or  **`@`**,  removes  the  entire
> array.

Comment: Note that shell array syntax is really just a way to make it easy to deal with similarly named variables. There is no *array* itself; in fact, after you write `a=()`, the variable `a` is still undefined until you actually assign to one of its indices.

Comment: @John1024: Thank you for this answer. Could you possibly expand it to include a suggested answer for achieving the intended result?

Comment: @AnthonyWebber Sure.  I added a section to the answer to show how to force a renumbering of the indices.

Comment: Just to mention an alternative approach (which might be a better fit for some code): instead of `unset numbers[4]`, assign the whole array using slicing, i.e. `numbers=("${numbers[@]:0:4}" "${numbers[@]:5}")` (I would post as an answer, but don't have time to properly explain).

Comment: @John1024: Appreciate you doing that. And thnx Toby :)

Answer (score 6):

`bash` arrays like in `ksh`, are not really arrays, they're more like associative arrays with keys limited to positive integers (or so called *sparse arrays*). For a shell with real arrays, you can have a look at shells like `rc`, `es`, `fish`, `yash`, `zsh` (or even `csh`/`tcsh` though those shells have so many issues they're better avoided).

#### In `zsh`:

```
a=(1 2 3 4 5)
a[3]=() # remove the 3rd element
a[1,3]=() # remove the first 3 elements
a[-1]=() # remove the last element
```

(Note that in zsh, `unset 'a[3]'` actually sets it to the empty string for improved compatibility with `ksh`)

#### in `yash`:

```
a=(1 2 3 4 5)
array -d a 3 # remove the 3rd element
array -d a 1 2 3 # remove the first 3 elements
array -d a -1 # remove the last element
```

#### in `fish` (not a Bourne-like shell contrary to `bash`/`zsh`):

```
set a 1 2 3 4 5
set -e a[3] # remove the 3rd element
set -e a[1..3] # remove the first 3 elements
set -e a[-1] # remove the last element
```

#### in `es` (based on `rc`, not Bourne-like)

```
a = 1 2 3 4 5
a = $a(... 2 4 ...) # remove the 3rd element
a = $a(4 ...) # remove the first 3 elements
a = $a(... `{expr $#a - 1}) # remove the last element
# or a convoluted way that avoids forking expr:
a = $a(... <={@{*=$*(2 ...); return $#*} $a})
```

#### in `ksh` and `bash`

You can use the arrays as normal arrays if you do:

```
a=("${a[@]}")
```

after each delete or insert operations that may have made the list of indexes not contiguous or not start at 0. Also note that `ksh`/`bash` arrays start at 0, not 1 (except for `$@` (in some ways)).

That will in effect tidy the elements and move them to index 0, 1, 2... in sequence.

Also note that you need to quote the `number[i]` in:

```
unset 'number[i]'
```

Otherwise, that would effectively run `unset numberi` if there was a file called `numberi` in the current directory.

Comment: I think the manual page for bash should be changed regarding "unset  name[subscript] destroys  the array element at index subscript.". Maybe "unset  name[subscript] destroys  the array element **with** index subscript." would be enough, or emphasize that bash has arrays allowing for non-consecutive indices (just like a hash table where the keys are natural numbers including zero).