# Insert variable in variable line using sed or awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

i have two variables (txt and a line number) i want to insert my txt in the x line

```
card=$(shuf -n1 shuffle.txt)
i=$(shuf -i1-52 -n1)
```

'card' is my txt : a card randomly selected in a shuffle 'deck'
and i want to insert it at a random line (i)

Comment: Just a tip: if your purpose is just to learn Bash that's fine (although there are better projects to sharpen your shell knowledge), but if your purpose is to make a functional card game, even just a toy one for your own use, I *strongly* recommend you use a different language than the shell.  [Shells are for *orchestration,* not really for programming.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303387/135943)

Comment: Yeah i need to learn something better because "graphics" are awfull, i use unicode for cards lol... it just a memory training tool, learn the deck then move a random card and find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `txt` is assigned to the text you wish to add, and that `i` is assigned to the line number at which to insert the text, this will output what is desired:

```
$ awk -v line="$i" -v text="$txt" '{print} NR==line{print text}' /path/to/textfile
```

A slight modification to add `text` to the specified line number (in addition to the text already there), rather than add it *after* the existing line `i` (on a line by its own) as the code above does:

```
$ awk -v line="$i" -v text="$txt" ' NR!=line{print} NR==line{print $0 text}' /path/to/textfile
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, that will *append* `txt` at the line number in question, not insert it.  (It will be on a line by itself, but its line number will be `i+1`, not `i`.)

Comment: Fair point.  Alternate take added which will append, rather than insert.

Answer (score 0):

Using a file as your data structure is going to incur some heavy performance penalties on your application, but you can insert the contents of variable `foo` at line number `i` in `file.txt` as follows:

```
printf '%s\n' "${i}i" "$foo" . x | ex file.txt
```

If the variable `foo` contains newlines this has some edge cases, but otherwise it will work regardless of any special characters, etc., providing only that the variable `i` has a valid line number (i.e. it can't be greater than the number of lines in `file.txt`).

But, again, using line numbers of files as your data structure is a horribly inefficient way to shuffle a deck of cards.  So beware.